# Pandas Resampling with delta time after specific starting time

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby, resampling

After reading a CSV into a data frame, I am trying to resample my "Value" column to 5 seconds, starting from the first rounded second of the time value. I would like to have the mean for all the values within the next 5 seconds, starting from 46:19.6 (format %M:%S:%f). So the code would give me the mean for 46:20, then 46:25, and so on...Does anybody know how to do this? Thank you!

input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Time': {0: '46:19.6',
  1: '46:20.7',
  2: '46:21.8',
  3: '46:22.9',
  4: '46:24.0',
  5: '46:25.1',
  6: '46:26.2',
  7: '46:27.6',
  8: '46:28.7',
  9: '46:29.8',
  10: '46:30.9',
  11: '46:32.0',
  12: '46:33.2',
  13: '46:34.3',
  14: '46:35.3',
  15: '46:36.5',
  16: '46:38.8',
  17: '46:40.0'},
 'Value': {0: 0,
  1: 1,
  2: 2,
  3: 3,
  4: 4,
  5: 5,
  6: 6,
  7: 8,
  8: 9,
  9: 10,
  10: 11,
  11: 12,
  12: 13,
  13: 14,
  14: 15,
  15: 17,
  16: 19,
  17: 20}})
```

Comment: if you do `df.info()` or (where `df` is the name of your dataframe), what format is your time column in? `Timedelta` , `DateTime` or an `object`

Comment: RangeIndex: 18 entries, 0 to 17 @DavidErickson

Comment: You have to look below that to find the columns.

Comment: by the way @CharlesWagner , for future questions, please provide input data and expected output data. You can copy your data from excel and then run the following code `pd.read_clipboard().to_dict()` and then press the {} Code Sample button on StackOverFlow and paste in the dictionary data to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `Time` field is in `datetime64[ns]` format, you simply can use `pd.Grouper` and pass `freq=5S`:

```
# next line of code is optional to transform to datetime format if the `Time` field is an `object` i.e. string.
# df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime('00:'+df['Time'])

df1 = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Time', freq='5S'))['Value'].mean().reset_index()

#Depending on what you want to do, you can also replace the above line of code with one of two below:
#df1 = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Time', freq='5S'))['Value'].mean().reset_index().iloc[1:]
#df1 = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Time', freq='5S', base=4.6))['Value'].mean().reset_index()
#In the above line of code 4.6s can be adjusted to whatever number between 0 and 5.
df1
```

output:

```
    Time                 Value
0   2020-07-07 00:46:15  0.0
1   2020-07-07 00:46:20  2.5
2   2020-07-07 00:46:25  7.6
3   2020-07-07 00:46:30  12.5
4   2020-07-07 00:46:35  17.0
5   2020-07-07 00:46:40  20.0
```

Full reproducible code from an example DataFrame I created:

```
import re
import pandas
df = pd.DataFrame({'Time': {0: '46:19.6',
  1: '46:20.7',
  2: '46:21.8',
  3: '46:22.9',
  4: '46:24.0',
  5: '46:25.1',
  6: '46:26.2',
  7: '46:27.6',
  8: '46:28.7',
  9: '46:29.8',
  10: '46:30.9',
  11: '46:32.0',
  12: '46:33.2',
  13: '46:34.3',
  14: '46:35.3',
  15: '46:36.5',
  16: '46:38.8',
  17: '46:40.0'},
 'Value': {0: 0,
  1: 1,
  2: 2,
  3: 3,
  4: 4,
  5: 5,
  6: 6,
  7: 8,
  8: 9,
  9: 10,
  10: 11,
  11: 12,
  12: 13,
  13: 14,
  14: 15,
  15: 17,
  16: 19,
  17: 20}})
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime('00:'+df['Time'])
df1 = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Time', freq='5S'))['Value'].mean().reset_index()
df1
```

Comment: Thanks @DavidErickson! But this starts from 2020-07-07 00:46:15, I would like the code to have it starting from the first rounded second of the time value. So it would start from for 2020-07-07 00:46:20, then 2020-07-07 00:46:25, and so on...Would you know how to do this?

Comment: If the data frame started  at 2020-07-07 00:46:17 for example, then it should be 2020-07-07 00:46:17, then 2020-07-07 00:46:22; 2020-07-07 00:46:27....

Comment: you can pas `, base=4.6` or any number depending on your first value: `df1 = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Time', freq='5S', base=4.6))['Value'].mean().reset_index()`. Alternatively, you could drop the first row with `df1 = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Time', freq='5S'))['Value'].mean().reset_index().iloc[1:]`